# How can I list all gems in rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Recently I am diving into a tool about gems.

A feature requires to get the repos' address with given gems list.
I want to fetch all gems info in rubygems.org, and store them local, instead of searching them each time. Searching with a list of gem name will cost too much time.

However, I could not find response api in the api page of rubygems.org. There are apis to search with specific gem, or list all gems owned by some guys. But not the one lists all gems info in rubygems.org.

So, how can I list all gems in rubygems.org? Is there any 3-party api to do that?

Comment: Try to search without a value in the query parameter: `https://rubygems.org/api/v1/search.json?query=`. Note the result will be paginated.

Comment: @mccannf Given an empty query gets all gems! Interesting! The only problem left is **There are more than 80000 gems in rubygems.org**, and each request only fetches 30 gems...T_T Anyway, it is a possible way.

Comment: Yes, which kind of begs the question **why** you would want to retrieve all 80,000 and not just rely on the search API to find the gems you want. Even if you managed to retrieve all of them, a % are being upgraded or changed all the time!

Comment: If you want to know all gems available, then you'll be hitting the gems repo very hard when you make a request, which is a bad idea. Instead, consider becoming a slave and then hitting your own local cache. You'll know what's recent and can hit it all day long without impacting anyone else.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `gem search` without an argument returns the full list of all gems on RubyGems.org. The URLs on RubyGems follow a simple pattern, therefore, you can start playing around with gem names with a simple class like this:

```
class GemRepo
  attr_reader :names

  def initialize
    @names = []
    load_names
  end

  def size
    @names.size
  end

  def urls
    @names.map { |name| "https://rubygems.org/gems/#{name}" }
  end

private
  def load_names
    `gem search`.each_line do |line|
      next if line.empty? || line.match(/\*/)
      @names << line.split().first
    end
  end
end

gem_repo = GemRepo.new

gem_repo.size
# => 88679
gem_repo.names
# => ['-', '0mq', ..., 'Zzzzz', 'zzzzzz']
gem_repo.urls
# => ['https://rubygems.org/gems/-', 'https://rubygems.org/gems/0mq', ..., 'https://rubygems.org/gems/Zzzzz', 'https://rubygems.org/gems/zzzzzz']
```

Comment: Err...The result of `gem search` doestn't return the repo url of gems. And `gem search -d` takes too much time...Anyway, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @罗泽轩 I updated my answer with an example how to build the gem's homepage url. You may want to follow the same pattern to create the download url. To receive the repository url is not that simple. Especially because there are lot of Gems without a link to a repository.